# Multiple layouts inside the single viewStub

Tags: android, performance, layout, viewstub

I have an item which has apple, pear and lemon. I made separate layouts for apples, pears and lemons.

I want to get the layout of that element if any element is selected. I tried that put the correct layout to viewStub according to selected layout with `inflate()` function. But the performance of defining layouts with `inflate()` each time was exhausting and sometimes caused incorrect work.

Please help me.

**My general view codes:**

```
    public class MyView extends RelativeLayout  {
    private ViewStub viewStub;
    private int lemon = 1, apple = 2, pear = 3;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        this.viewStub = ViewUtil.findById(this, R.id.view_stub);
    }

    public void bindElements(int type){
    if (type == lemon) {castLemon(); return;} 
    if (type == apple ) {castApple(); return;} 
    if (type == pear) {castPear(); return;} 

     public void castLemon() {

            viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.lemon_item);
            LemonView lemonView = (LemonView) viewStub.inflate();
        }
     }

    public void castApple() {

            viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.apple_item);
            AppleView appleView = (AppleView) viewStub.inflate();
        }
     }

    public void castPear() {

            viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.pear_item);
            PearView pearView = (PearView) viewStub.inflate();
        }
     }
  }
```

**My general view xml:**

```
<com.android.android.MyView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bodyLinear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                       <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/view_stub"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

</com.android.android.MyView>
```

**LemonView.java:**

```
public class LemonView extends FrameLayout {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public LemonView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public LemonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public LemonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        inflate(context, R.layout.lemon_view, this);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
```

**lemon_view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.android.android.LemonView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</merge>
```

**lemon_item xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.android.android.LemonView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lemon_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create all the layouts at once, then just show / hide the needed layout variant with `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` / `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Comment: please help me. Which one should I do : viewStub.setVisibility(View.GONE); or viewStub.inflate().setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I just meant to have several `viewStubLemon`, `viewStubApple` and `viewStubPear` instead of single `viewStub` and choose it like `viewStubLemon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); viewStubApple.setVisibility(View.GONE); viewStubPear.setVisibility(View.GONE);` (the sample is for Lemon)

Comment: Yes, hide/show is very fast in comparison to inflating